# Como reeordenar uma ViewBag, dentro da View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer com que uma ViewBag que recebeu uma lista na controladora, ser reordenada após a alteração em uma combobox sem que a página seja recarregada.

Passando a Lista para a ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Answers(int id)
        {
            List<Respostas> Respostas = _Control.ViewRespostas(id);
            Respostas = Respostas.OrderBy(p => p.DataResposta).ToList();
            Pergunta aPergunta = _Control.SelecionarPergunta(id);
            Usuario oUsuario = _Control.SelecionarUsuario(aPergunta.Per_IDUsuario);
            ViewBag.Usuario = oUsuario.Usu_UserName;
            ViewBag.Quantidade = Respostas.Count();
            ViewBag.Respostas = Respostas;
            ViewBag.LDPergunta = _Control.ViewLikesDeslikesPergunta(id);
            return View(aPergunta);
        }
```

E na Página Answers estou usando essa ViewBag pra popular as respostas da Pergunta em Questão:

```
foreach (var x in ViewBag.Respostas)
                    {
                        <hr />
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImagem", new { codigo = x.Res_IDUsuario })" class="img-circle img-responsive ImagemUsuario" />
                                </div>
                                <h5 class="text-center">@x.Usu_Name</h5>
                                <h5 class="text-center">@x.DataResposta</h5>
                                <span class="btn btn-success Like" onclick="LikeDeslike(@x.Res_ID,'Like')"><span id="quantidadeLikes@(x.Res_ID)">@x.QuantidadeLikes</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></span>
                                <span class="btn btn-danger Deslike" onclick="LikeDeslike(@x.Res_ID,'Deslike')"><span id="quantidadeDeslikes@(x.Res_ID)">@x.QuantidadeDeslikes</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></span>
                                <br />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <span align="left">@Html.Raw(@x.Res_Message)</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

O resultado ficou o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando o usuário alterasse o valor na combobox deveria reordenar essas respostas sem recarregar a página, consigo mandar uma requisição em ajax e estou recebendo a resposta com os objetos ordenados, mas não sei oque teria que fazer
para que esse foreach recarregue com as respostas ordenadas:
requisição em Ajax:

```
 $("#Filtro").change(function () {
                var Url = "@Url.Action("OrdenaRespostas", "Questions")";
                var Valor = $(this).val();
                $.post(Url, { id: @Model.Per_ID, Filtro: Valor }, AtualizaRespostas);
            });
```

Controladora que recebe a requisição:

```
   public ActionResult OrdenaRespostas(int id,string Filtro)
        {
            if(Filtro!="")
            {
                List<Respostas> Respostas = _Control.ViewRespostas(id);
                if(Filtro=="recentes")
                {
                    Respostas = Respostas.OrderBy(p => p.DataResposta).ToList();
                }

                else if(Filtro=="antigas")
                {
                    Respostas = Respostas.OrderByDescending(p => p.DataResposta).ToList();
                }

                else if(Filtro=="like")
                {
                    Respostas = Respostas.OrderBy(p => p.QuantidadeLikes).ToList();
                }

                else if(Filtro=="deslike")
                {
                    Respostas = Respostas.OrderBy(p => p.QuantidadeDeslikes).ToList();
                }
                return Json(Respostas);
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Função que está recebendo a resposta:

```
function AtualizaRespostas(resposta) {
                $("@ViewBag.Respostas").html(resposta);
            }
```

esse parâmetro resposta está pegando a resposta em json da controladora, mas agr não sei oque fazer para que aquele foreach, seja reordenado...

Comment: Substitua as imagens pelo código

Answer (score 0):

Você deve limpar sua `ComboBox` e colocar os itens ordenados após isto

**Limpar ComboBox**

```
$("#IdDaSuaComboBox").empty();
```

**Adicionar novos itens**

```
$.each(resposta, function (i, obj) {
    $("#IdDaSuaComboBox").append('<option value="' + obj.Value + '">' + obj.Text + '</option>');
});
```

Você ira fazer isto na sua função `AtualizaRespostas`

Comment: Não é a comboBox mais sim as respostas da página